# Limitation of building a simple AWS-based app on Gradio

Tags: flask, gradio

I am working on a web application that has to interact with AWS.

Mores specifically, I envision the app to have:

- A login page
- After login, the app assigns in the backend an AWS role to the logged user. The user is redirected to the home page.

On the home page, the user has 2 functionalities:

- Upload data to an S3 bucket (one upload file module, that allows them to pass a json file to the backend and upload it to s3 with boto3)
- Run a lambda function (that is pass a string to the backend that then runs a lambda function with the string as input; I already have the backend part)

Now: I know how to do the backend, but I have zero experience with frontend development; I don't care if the UI is clunky; but I do care about security (I will need to distribute this to customers). I am exploring options for frameworks to build the app's frontend, and I am considering using Gradio.

Questions:

1. What are the limitations of Gradio in building a simple app like the one described above?
2. As an alternative, I am considering Flask + some basic HTML / CSS. But I have no idea how they work, and I feel that the learning curve is steep. Am I right?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

1. Gradio

- You can certainly do some authentication (either basic or oauth). This page has both [Gradio Authentication](https://www.gradio.app/guides/sharing-your-app#o-auth-login-via-hugging-face).
- I found this example for integrating gradio with s3 buckets. https://modal.com/docs/examples/cloud_bucket_mount_loras

2. Flask

- Flask and basic html are quite easy (even with only minimal python experience). [Flask](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) took very little time to grasp.
- It also supports auth (Basic and OAuth). [Flask Oauth](https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/flask/how-to-implement-flask-oauth/)
- Here's a sample (without auth) I [wrote](https://github.com/asutermo/TheConversationSentimentAnalysis/blob/main/app/main.py) that uses Quart (an async version of flask) to showcase how easy it is to build. I'm not a frontend person. The sample renders templates (html) and fills them with basic information.

You'll definitely be able to do everything you need with Flask relatively easily.